# SMTP relay check (test) (Postfix)

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, zabbix

I want to add item/trigger to Zabbix to check that some server A can send mails via mail server B (SMTP relay) **without sending on real/fake email** and I haven't a problem with firewall/iptables rules and postfix rules. Mail service belongs to me and I use Postfix / CentOS 7.

How can I do it?

I know that I can send real mail via mailx or netcat, the command will be something like this:

```
echo "Test message" | mailx -v -r "from@some.com" -s "Some subject" -S smtp="mail-server-b.com:25" to@some.org
```

and parse result but I don't want to do it.

Comment: Search for "swaks"! This is the Siwss Army knife for email - it can do all the things.

Comment: You say you don't want to send an email then describe a mechanism which sends an email. The only solution would be to check the running processes and build a full config file auditor for the MTAs at each end (i.e. a piece of software which is significantly more complex than the thing you are trying to monitor). Just send an email.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that reliably. You can check whether you get connection to the SMTP port, for example, but it does not mean you will be able to send the mail. Mail could be rejected or removed at any later stage. The only way to reliably test this is to send a test email periodically.

Comment: If I check only port, it means that I check only firewall/iptables rules. But I need to check relay too. Thanks for answer.